# Can I sort items ignoring leading space in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-admin

I'm working on a Django (v1.4.22) app that has many repeated items, except for a space, so the admin sorts it "wrong".

I know the proper solution would be to whack some SQL and remove those spaces, but for the moment I'd like to help our users. Also I can't just yet since the name field is UNIQUE, etc etc.

```
class Meta:
    get_latest_by = 'date_created'
    ordering = ['name'] // --> Can I do something with this, like name.strip()?
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to using `ordering` shown by Paulo, you could change the default queryset to be ordered using "trimmed" values (assuming your database supports `TRIM`). Inside *admin.py*:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.extra(select={'trimmed_name':'TRIM(name)'}).order_by('trimmed_name')
    return qs
```

*(Note: This is added as Django database function in the development branch as `Trim`)*

Answer (score 3):

You can use [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/) in `ordering`; in particular, you can use [Func() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions). In your case:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func

...

class Meta:
    get_latest_by = 'date_created'
    ordering = [Func(F('name'), function='TRIM')]
```

I tested this on PostgreSQL and it worked.

Comment: cool, didn't know this way, I always override `get_queryset` to do this.

Comment: I get a `Error: cannot import name Func`, using Django 1.4.22

Comment: Django 1.4! That's old, `Func` was introduced in 1.8. You can try dirkgroten's answer.

Comment: I know :( Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list (or orther iterable collection) of strings, you can do the following:

```
mylist = [some strings]
mylist.sort(key=lambda s: s.strip())
```

This will sort `mylist`, ignoring left/right spacing without actually deleting the spaces

Comment: This won't work for the admin views, as you need to order the queryset, not a list.